# Javascript function to remove all digits from a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What's a Javascript function to remove all digits from a string using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> var s = '92393293232abc323'
>>> s = s.replace( /\d+/g, '' )
'abc'
```